# Problem with UV unwrap, collapsing vertices

Tags: texturing, uv

I am somewhat new to modeling but I have done uv's a few times before, but for some reason, I can't get it to work right this time. I have marked seams and set up a blank texture but when I unwrap (using the basic "unwrap") it comes out really strange, with most of the islands being a diamond shape.(Edit) I have deleted all seams and started from scratch and the same problem persists so it cant be from modifying the mesh after the uv is made. [image: Example[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtO7Z.png)

Comment: Attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to inspect whats the problem is

Comment: The vertices in your uv map are pinned, did you try selecting them in UV editor and unpin with Alt+P?

Comment: @MrZak This fixed the problem, thank you so much! :D

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42807/having-a-uv-maping-problem-does-anyone-know-what-this-is-and-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had pinned vertices(They are red when pinned), the fix was as simple as selecting all vertices in the uv editor and pressing Alt-p. Thank you so much, Mr Zak for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Yo it might be because there are so many curves on your mesh , you can unwrap it , try cube projection sometimes it help me out for applying texture , otherwise you might have to mark your seam on 2 part ( front and back  ) might be more easy too

Comment: Adding more seams doesn't seem to help and cube project breaks it up too much.